# jquery selector exclude elements containing input with focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I spent quite a bit of time trying to come up with this today to no avail.

I'm trying to select rows in a table having visible input elements but excluding the row that contains the input with focus.

My best guesses:

```
$('tr:has(input:visible)').not('tr:has(input:focus)')
$('tr:has(input:visible):not(:has(input:focus))')
```

Neither of these remove the row with the focused input. I read that :focus is a pseudo selector, is that part of my problem or is that a label for everything with a colon?

Is it possible to do this within the selector? I could also just loop through manually with a conditional, but I'd like to be able to avoid that.

Comment: Looping through manually with a conditional is exactly what jQuery is doing behind the scenes for those selectors, just fyi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to return `tr` elements with `input` elements that aren't focused.

In this case, [`.is(':focus')`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) is used to determine whether the child `input` is focused. If it ***isn't***, then it is returned and added to the collection of `tr` elements.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/62b0mf9v/)

```
var tr = $('tr:has(input:visible)').filter(function () {
    return !$('input', this).is(':focus');
});
```

---

Based on [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/c28t9oz3/), though, it looks like both of your original jQuery selectors were working properly. Perhaps you are querying the DOM when the `input` element doesn't have focus?

Comment: `.filter` need to return a boolean, not the object. it should be `return !$('input', this).is(':focus')`. Your function is a bit overkill now.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Thanks, I didn't realize I could do that--updated :)

Comment: I think I must have been hitting a race condition with setting focus then, thanks for the fiddle setup (and the custom filter function)

Answer (score 1):

Updated, actually I tested your two jQuery selectors in your question, and those were working correctly based on my test :-) The length of how many elements are found based on the query are printed to the console.

```js
$("#firstInput").focus(); // set focus


console.log($('tr:has(input:visible)').not('tr:has(input:focus)').length) // 2

console.log($('tr:has(input:visible):not(:has(input:focus))').length); // 2

//$('tr:has(input:visible):not(:has(input:focus))').remove(); // removes two rows

//$('tr:has(input:visible)').not('tr:has(input:focus)').remove() // removes two rows
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Inputs</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Peter</td>
         <td>
            <input id="firstInput" type="text"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="firstIIInput" type="text"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lois</td>
        <td>
            <input id="2ndInput" type="text"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="2ndIIInput" type="text"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gabriel</td>
        <td>
            <input id="3rdInput" type="text"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="3rdIIInput" type="text"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```